# How can I get records between two dates from CSV file by setting an environment variable (To date, From Date and List of project) in gitlab CICD?

Tags: python, csv, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am having multiple project in my git repository so I have develop a code in python through which I can get info of all the commits made by each and every developer and for all the records a csv file get generated with a header list Date,Submitted,Gitlab_url,Project,Branch,Status,Username,Ticket,Subject.

Now I want to generate a csv file for the particular dates and for a particular project by setting an environment variable (To date, From Date and List of project) in gitlab CICD.

I mean user will entre To Date , From Date and Project id in CICD and run the pipeline and for the same csv report should get generated.

If user is not inserting To Date , From Date and Project id and running the pipeline then by default csv for all the commits should be generate.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t feel like something CI should be doing - it should be used to test projects building, running unit tests or integrations and stuff like that.

This feels like an admin task that could be performed by hand.

That being said, you can achieve the functionality you want by creating a schedule within gitlab, a schedule allows you to define variables and their values. Use these variables as input for your python script to output the csv and then you can just click to run the schedule and change the values when you need to.